# I stepped on another [lego]. Let's clean these up

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

We have three tags here

- [lego](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lego)
- [mindstorms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mindstorms)
- [nxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nxt)

They're currently in a bizarre love-triangle thing where they're being mixed up all over the place.  [Lego Mindstorms NXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_NXT) was a thing, but not anymore. [mindstorms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mindstorms) is on-topic (for programming questions), but probably should be renamed [lego-mindstorms]. [lego](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lego) should probably be merged with the renamed [lego-mindstorms] tag.

Comment: I felt a sharp phantom pain while reading that title

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Yeah, we need need to be more [environmentally friendly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yugBY.jpg) on this as well

Comment: A million years from now mankind will be long gone. And the Lego will remain.

Comment: NXT is not a thing anymore? :( RIP. It introduced me to programming along Comenius Logo, Pascal and Game Maker.

Comment: So someone poured lego all over the floor, played for a while, then got tired of it and now we must clean it up?

Comment: There is also [tag:ev3]. which is the successor to [tag:nxt]. And there are 3 tags related to alternative languages/tools: [tag:nxt-python], [tag:lejos-nxj], [tag:nxc]

Comment: @gre_gor I've renamed [ev3] to [lego-mindstorms-ev3]